# kick command at a Discord bot doesn't do anything

Tags: discord.js

I don't know why my code doesn't do anything.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!kick")) {
        if (message.mentions.members()) {
            message.mentions.members.kick().then((member) => {
                message.channel.send(member.displayName + "a luat kick");
            }).catch(() => {
                message.channel.send("no perm");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your bot have kick permissions in that server?

Comment: he has admin on my server

Comment: The common mistake most users make, is not enabling intents when initializing the client. Did you enable any intents?

Comment: i have "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"

Comment: `message.mentions.members` is a Collection, not a function or a member. You'll want to call `.first()` on the collection to get the member you mentioned. Check *that* in your if statment and kick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.mentions.members` does not work. I believe this way is better:

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member) return message.reply('Please specify a member!');

try {
    member.kick()
    message.channel.send('Kick the specified user successfully!');
} catch(e) {
    message.channel.send('There was an error kicking this member!);
}
```

`!` This only works for `Discord.js@13+`

Also, check if you have enabled `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent.

Comment: Make sure to `await` the promises so that errors are caught

Answer (score 0):

`message.mentions.members()` is not a function, try changing it to `message.mentions.members.size`.

Also, make sure you have the GuildMembers intent.